Issue with Debezium Snapshot: DateTimeParseException in PostgreSQL Connector
I'm encountering an issue with Debezium version 2.3.1 while processing a snapshot from a PostgreSQL database. The error occurs during the snapshot phase and seems to be related to parsing a date/time value. The specific error message is:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException:     
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'f' could not be parsed at index 0
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.DateTimeFormat$ISODateTimeFormat.format(DateTimeFormat.java:166)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.DateTimeFormat$ISODateTimeFormat.timestampToInstant(DateTimeFormat.java:172)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.AbstractColumnValue.asInstant(AbstractColumnValue.java:81)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.ReplicationMessageColumnValueResolver.resolveValue(ReplicationMessageColumnValueResolver.java:110)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.pgoutput.PgOutputReplicationMessage.getValue(PgOutputReplicationMessage.java:92)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.pgoutput.PgOutputMessageDecoder$1.getValue(PgOutputMessageDecoder.java:748)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresChangeRecordEmitter.columnValues(PostgresChangeRecordEmitter.java:179)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresChangeRecordEmitter.getNewColumnValues(PostgresChangeRecordEmitter.java:125)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.emitCreateRecord(RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.java:69)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.emitChangeRecords(RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.java:47)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresChangeRecordEmitter.emitChangeRecords(PostgresChangeRecordEmitter.java:94)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher.dispatchDataChangeEvent(EventDispatcher.java:296)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'f' could not be parsed at index 0
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1874)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.DateTimeFormat$ISODateTimeFormat.lambda$timestampToInstant$3(DateTimeFormat.java:172)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.DateTimeFormat$ISODateTimeFormat.format(DateTimeFormat.java:162)

This issue arises when using a table configured for incremental snapshots. Here is an example of the connector configuration I’m using:
*
*{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
  "connector.displayName": "PostgreSQL",
  "database.user": "docker",
  "database.dbname": "exampledb",
  "transforms": "unwrap",
  "database.server.name": "localhost",
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "60000",
  "database.port": "5432",
  "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
  "slot.max.retries": "10",
  "schema.include.list": "public",
  "slot.retry.delay.ms": "15000",
  "heartbeat.action.query": "INSERT INTO public.debezium_heartbeat VALUES ('debezium', now())",
  "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
  "database.hostname": "postgres",
  "database.password": "docker",
  "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
  "signal.data.collection": "public.debezium_signal",
  "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
  "table.include.list": "public.table, public.debezium_signal",
  "max.batche.size": "65000",
  "max.queue.size": "275000",
  "incremental.snapshot.chunk.size": "6500",
  "connector.id": "postgres",
  "topic.prefix": "db-prod"
}**


The error seems related to a date/time field in the snapshot data, as indicated by the DateTimeParseException with the text 'f', suggesting a potential issue with date/time formatting or parsing.
DDL for my table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass),
    federal_tax_id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    external_id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phone character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    cellphone character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_street character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_street_number character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_complement character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_city_district character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_post_code character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_city character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_city_code character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_state_code character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_country character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address_latitude numeric,
    address_longitude numeric,
    address_geo geometry(Point,4326) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (st_setsrid(st_makepoint((address_longitude)::double precision, (address_latitude)::double precision), 4326)) STORED,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    is_company boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    state_tax_id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    official_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

Applications Versions:
Debezium: 2.3.1
PostgreSQL: 13.15
I tried to reproduce the error using the same version of Debezium and the error occurred when I took a snapshot and then performed an update with the following query:
UPDATE public.table
SET updated_at = current_timestamp
WHERE id = 28948709;
example snapshot incremental:
INSERT INTO debezium_signal (id, type, data)
VALUES (
  'sdadsada-sdasdas-9b45-12608f88b2a6',
  'execute-snapshot',
  '{"data-collections": ["public.table"]}'
);

I could integrate cdc with streaming, but I need the history.
Updated:
I enabled logs in debezium and found this:
024-08-10 22:09:43,120 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,121 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,121 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,122 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,123 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,123 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,123 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,124 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,124 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,125 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,126 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,126 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
2024-08-10 22:09:43,127 ERROR  Postgres|company-db-prod|streaming  Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column 'address_geo' not found in result set 'id, federal_tax_id, external_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, cellphone, address_street, address_street_number, address_complement, address_city_district, address_post_code, address_city, address_city_code, address_state_code, address_country, address_latitude, address_longitude, address_geo, created_at, updated_at, is_company, state_tax_id, official_name' for table 'public.table', columns: {

address_geo is not in the schema registry. could this cause problems?

You have left out the important parts 1) The complete error message. 2) The table definition. Update your question text with this information.

Thanks for your reply @AdrianKlaver. I updated it.


It looks like an issue with the Java DateTimeFormatter. 2) You will need to find what the actual value is that is being passed in. At this point I would suspect a boolean string 'f'.


@AdrianKlaver I think you're right, I enabled tracing and found that an address_geo column is not in the schema registry. Could this cause problems?
In the database I did not find anything unusual in the records of this table in the columns that appear in the logs. Do you have any idea how I can resolve this? skip or set null columns with corrupted data?


Why is this Failed to properly convert data value for 'public.table.is_company' of type bool happening. I am not seeing that you are updating is_company. 2) address_geo is a GENERATED column, could that be causing an issue with Debezium?



Sorry, I think I explained it wrong, these logs are from my production environment and not from my laboratory where I try to reproduce this problem through a simple update by id set timestamp. In my production environment, insert and update always, and is_company has a default value of false.
I don't think so, because I have another table with the same column and I don't have any problems.
I think I opened up the options too much and lost track of the real cause.


At this point I am completely lost as to what you are doing and what the issue is. My suggestion is to create a complete test case that illustrates the issue. Then delete this question and create a new question with the test case.

@AdrianKlaver I appreciate your help. I discovered the cause of the problem, this only happens in the pgouput plugin, in decoderbufs I didn't find the same scenario. I managed to trace it and find the problem, I was advised to open an bug in Jira:
https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-8150
For check discussion of the case check this link:
https://debezium.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/348249-community-postgresql/topic/Issue.20with.20Debezium.20Snapshot.3A.20DateTimeParseException.20in.20Post

I discovered the cause of the problem, this only happens in the pgouput plugin, in decoderbufs I didn't find the same scenario. I managed to trace it and find the problem, I was advised to open an bug in Jira:
https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-8150
For check discussion of the case check this link:
https://debezium.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/348249-community-postgresql/topic/Issue.20with.20Debezium.20Snapshot.3A.20DateTimeParseException.20in.20Post
